# Not getting notification when I get messaged by a random number

Tags: ios

I seem to not get any notifications when I get a text message by a random number. This can be infuriating when getting a verification code or such. I still get the "1" next the icon but thats it, I get no notice.

Comment: Are messages syncing somewhere ?like Mac

Comment: nope. I'm not getting anything there